# MYSQL table optimization + PHP query on it

Tags: php, mysql

I have data in a csv file with 4000 columns and 8000 rows.  The first column is the ID of individuals (i.e., there are 8000 individuals).  Each individual has 4000 fields of data.

I have 30 of these csv files, each representing a different time period (so there are 30 time periods). The second column in each csv file has the time period.

My end goal is to do a php query that allow me to select one individual and view all the the data for that individual, i.e., 30 rows (1 row per period) and 4000 columns.

What is the best way to structure a MYSQL table to handle this?  One giant MYSQL table (4000 columns x 240,000 rows)?

Comment: 5k columns?? not possible in a single mysql table Quote from mysql doc: `There is a hard limit of 4096 columns per table, but the effective maximum may be less for a given table. The exact limit depends on several interacting factors, ....`

Comment: The first question is why is there 5k columns in your input and can this data be normalized somehow?

Comment: That is the format in which I received the data

Comment: You should split up the columns into multiple tables. mysql cannot hold even 4k columns unless your average field size is < 15 bytes (<5 chars utf8) and you are using MyISAM storage engine (InnoDB has a 1000 column limit) Reference [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/column-count-limit.html)

Comment: Although I rarely advocate the EAV data model, this might be one instance where I would.